# Files restored to Starbound's workshop folder won't appear ingame

Tags: steam, starbound, steam-workshop

I previously backed up all my Starbound mods needed for a save, and now some files are corrupted and I want to restore my copy of the contents of the *workshop/content/211820* folder that I saved on my Google Drive. When I put them back into the *211820* folder, Steam does not show the mods as subscribed, and they do not appear in-game.
Verifying game integrity and restarting Steam or my computer has no effects.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to **subscribe to the mods again** in the Workshop. That should trigger Steam to look for their respective content in said folder.

Comment: I donk know what the mods are, Is there any way I can tell from the filenames?

Comment: @LorenMeehan: The foldername should be the mod ID, which also appears in the workshop URL